# DEVICE_STATE(SIP/mypeer) in Asterisk returning only UNAVAILABLE and NOT_INUSE, not returning other status why?

Tags: asterisk, sip, pbx

`DEVICE_STATE(SIP/mypeer)` is returning only `UNAVAILABLE` and `NOT_INUSE` but not the other available options such as `UNKNOWN`, `INUSE`, `BUSY`, `INVALID`, `RINGING`, `RINGINUSE`, `ONHOLD`.

```
exten=>1,NoOp(SIP/mypeer has state ${DEVICE_STATE(SIP/mypeer)})
same=>2,ExecIf($[${DEVICE_STATE(SIP/mypeer)}=NOT_INUSE]?Goto(5):Goto(2))
```

Here I am expecting the `device_state` should return `busy`, `ringing`, `inuse` or `onhold` at `mypeer` while getting a second call but I am getting only `UNAVAILABLE` and `NOT_INUSE` as output.

I already set `callcounter=yes` and `call-limit=1000`. What should I do now?

Answer (score 1):

`callcounter=yes` in [general] section sip.conf

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 1):

as stated by the official page here:
[asterisk chan_sip state and presence](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/chan_sip+State+and+Presence+Options)

> The callcounter option in sip.conf must be enabled for SIP devices (e.g. SIP/Alice) to provide advanced device state. Without it you may see some state, such as unavailable or idle, but not much more.

Answer (score 0):

You have add

```
qualify=yes
```

to your peer if you want get other states.